# Make the rank input increase and decrease by one number and stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want make the rank input increase and decrease by one number and then stop, but it continues to put one next to the value:

```js
$(".plus").click(function() {
  var x = $(".minirank").val();
  $(".minirank").val(++x);
  var x2 = $("#Bigrank").val();
  $("#Bigrank").val(x2 + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Bigrank" value="900">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="plus">+</button>
<input class="minirank" value="0">
<button class="less">-</button>
```

Comment: You need to parseInt(x).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the values of the textboxes are strings, and when you add a number to a string like `x2+1`, JavaScript converts the number to a string and concatenate the two strings. You can use the `++` operator like you did for the `minirank` which forces JavaScript into converting the string into a number (or you can convert it manually if you like, for example using `parseInt()`). For the decrease button, just use `--`:

```js
$(".plus").click(function() {
  var x = $(".minirank").val();
  $(".minirank").val(++x);
  var x2 = $("#Bigrank").val();
  $("#Bigrank").val(++x2);
});

$(".less").click(function() {
  var x = $(".minirank").val();
  $(".minirank").val(--x);
  var x2 = $("#Bigrank").val();
  $("#Bigrank").val(--x2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Bigrank" value="900">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="plus">+</button>
<input class="minirank" value="0">
<button class="less">-</button>
```

Comment: And it should work best with `input type="number"` AFAIK

Comment: i know but i want Bigrank value increase just one and don't increase  again

Comment: Then put the code in an `if` statement.

Comment: I want the value to become 901 instead of just 900 and do not over it

Comment: Then surround the code with `if(x2 < 901) { }`.